# FIrst JavaScript script doesn't work. How to debug?

Tags: javascript, html, esp32

I am new to JavaScript and HTML. I have a webpage with some buttons that I am using as indicator lights. Not only that, but I set up the function to get a binary byte from the server and to set the lights on or off, only nothing happens. I am not sure how you are even supposed to debug something like this, but perhaps someone can spot and error.

```
      <script>
         function UpdateStatusLED() {
             var xhttp = new
             XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     int Status= Integer.parseInt(this.responseText);
                     if(Status & 1 == 1) {document.getElementById("OPENP").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("OPENP").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 2 == 1) {document.getElementById("CLOSEDP").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("CLOSEDP").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 4 == 1) {document.getElementById("OPENM").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("OPENM").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 8 == 1) {document.getElementById("CLOSEDM").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("CLOSEDM").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 16 == 1) {document.getElementById("RAIN").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("RAIN").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 32 == 1) {document.getElementById("SAFE").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("SAFE").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 64 == 1) {document.getElementById("CYCLE").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById(CYCLE").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
         
                     if(Status & 128 == 1) {document.getElementById("OPENCMD").style.background = '#3a0cf2' /* blue */;}
                     else {document.getElementById("OPENCMD").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
                 }
             };
             xhttp.open("GET", "/UpdateStatusLED", true);
             xhttp.send();
         }
         setInterval(function() {
             UpdateStatusLED();
         }, 1713);
      </script>
      <script>
         function ButtonPushed(x) {
           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open("GET", "/" + x, true);
           xhr.send();
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         function RoofIsOpen() {
             var xhttp = new
             XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     document.getElementById("RoofIsOpen").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                 }
             };
             xhttp.open("GET", "/RoofIsOpen", true);
             xhttp.send();
         }
         setInterval(function() {
             RoofIsOpen();
         }, 1713);
      </script>
```

I put a print in the server, and it seems that the UpdateStatusLED() does never to get. Below the first script are two of the scripts that actually work.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you are giving I can only spot 2 errors

**1:**

```js
int Status= Integer.parseInt(this.responseText);
//^
//|
//|- int doesn't exist in Javascript
```

**2:**

```js
else {document.getElementById(CYCLE").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
//                           ^ 
//                           |
//                           |- Missing opening "
```

Also this refactor will make your life way easier:

```js
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  const Status = Integer.parseInt(this.responseText);
  const dic = [
    {status: 1 << 0, id: 'OPENP'},
    {status: 1 << 1, id: 'CLOSEDP'},
    {status: 1 << 2, id: 'OPENM'},
    {status: 1 << 3, id: 'CLOSEDM'},
    {status: 1 << 4, id: 'RAIN'},
    {status: 1 << 5, id: 'SAFE'},
    {status: 1 << 6, id: 'CYCLE'},
    {status: 1 << 7, id: 'OPENCMD'},
  ]

  const colorRed  = '#f20505'
  const colorBlue = '#3a0cf2'

  const makeBlue = (id) => document.getElementById(id).style.background = colorBlue
  const makeRed  = (id) => document.getElementById(id).style.background = colorRed
  const updateEl = (e) => Status & e.status ? makeBlue(e.id) : makeRed(e.id)
  dic.forEach(updateEl)
}
```

To better understand your problem you can open the Developer Tools on your browser and go to the console and see if there's any error and maybe edit your post with more information.
Without this, I think I can't help you as you would like to.

See [Mozilla's Developer Tools Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools#the_javascript_debugger) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks Federico and Jose. I very much appreciate your help. I like your refactor. I don't understand it but I will try it and then study up on how it works.

Comment: First I used an array of objects to store the data you are using ordering status binary code and the id of each element.  `1 << 0` = one in position zero = 1, `1 << 1` = one in position 1 = 2, `1 << 2 = one in position 2 = 4, which is the way you used to compare things, but in a cleaner way (see Bitwise Operators) . Then I used Arrow Functions and the Ternary Operator for making the logic of applying the colors. And last forEach array method. Anytime mate! Tell us how it goes!

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a " here:

```
else {document.getElementById(CYCLE").style.background = '#f20505'; /* red*/;}
```

just before CYCLE